# Printers using RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL "Removal"

Tags: windows-7

Hi guys I was able to add the printer remotely  using this command

```
PS C:\WINDOWS> RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /gd /c\\computer name /n\\printerserver\printer name
```

My question is can I remove the same way using a wildcard factor. For example to remove all printers with the old server name?

Comment: @Thomas could you please help me? When I run this for a target workstation. I reviece an errpr stating "unable to add the per machine printer connection. The server print spooler service is not running" But it is running

Answer (score 1):

You can use native powershell commands: 
Get-Printer | where Name -like "*OLDSERVER*" | Remove-Printer